# How do i know which one is right mode for creating folder

Tags: php, file-permissions

im having hard time with this one, i want to create folder with write permisions, im doing it with `mkdir('folder', 0777)`

According to php manual  0777 is the widest possible access. but still after creating folder when i check it with `filezilla` i see write permision only on owner but public and group is unchecked, am i using wrong mode or something?

Comment: Since, [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php), 0777 is the default, why are you even specifying it?

Comment: yeah now that you mentioned it, it's pointless, but even so this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `umask` limits the permissions also.

There would hardly be a situation where 0777 is actually a correct, useful value; you should understand what you are doing and what permissions you need.

Comment: well i need permision to store files in that created folder

Comment: Then 0600 should suffice.  But I say it again: you need to understand the permissions model in order to use it properly.

Comment: with this one now not only i can't upload files but i can't delete folder too